# How do I lookup the UID of a domain user?

Tags: windows, active-directory, kerberos, ldap

I'm playing with golden ticket (mimikatz)

```
kerberos::golden /domain:vln2012.local /sid:S-1-5-21-3871786346-2057636518-1625323419 /rc4:8ad36fef31e071eac7ab9d54a093cb54 /user:user1 /id:1109 /groups:500,501,513,512,520,518,519 /ptt
```

By default it uses the UID of builtin Administrator account, which is `500`. How can I know the UID of other domain users?

I've tried the `Get-NetUser` cmdlet in PowerView, it only gave me a SID, which is not even a number.

Any ideas? I need to lookup the user ID outside DC

Comment: This is not so much a security question (although you want to use it for mimikatz) but a simple Windows internals question.